# C# WPF not getting internet for HTTPS request

Tags: c#, wpf, networking

i have a laptop after i open laptop from sleep get internet connection call back but HTTPS request timeout and when i debug then check call back is false ...

i check i get internet after 15-20 second from wakeup

code:-

```
if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()) return false;

   // however, this will include all adapters -- filter by opstatus and activity
   NetworkInterface[] interfaces = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
   return (from face in interfaces
                    where face.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
                    where (face.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel) && (face.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
                    where (!(face.Name.ToLower().Contains("virtual") || face.Description.ToLower().Contains("virtual")))
                    select face.GetIPv4Statistics()).Any(statistics => (statistics.BytesReceived > 0) && (statistics.BytesSent > 0));
```

i google and find the solution for what is the best way of get connection state..
so some people say ping or load google... but i have concern when i ping or load google many time so in the result google will block my IP ?

or ping/load google is the best way if not so what is the best way ?

AND For Information:- After wake up laptop from sleep Socket connect quickly only HTTPS request failed or Timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you just need an IP address to be check your internet connection. My current favourite IP address is to use the Google DNS servers. which are the IPv4 addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

[Read This what-is-the-best-ip-address-to-ping-to-test-my-internet-connection](http://etherealmind.com/what-is-the-best-ip-address-to-ping-to-test-my-internet-connection/)

Comment: 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 is Google DNS? .. if yes then after so many ping google will block my IP?

Comment: ya it's Google DNS. no google will not block IP but you can't ping in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check your internet connectivity you can do:

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping();
IPAddress address = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8");
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(address);

if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("NOT OK");
}
```

This essentially pings google's DNS server. If fails you might try ping 8.8.4.4. Just to make just, make those values configurable

Comment: 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 if Google DNS? .. if yes then after so many ping google will block my IP?

Comment: But i have concern after to many ping to Google DNS after that Google will block my IP address?

if yes google will block so what is the best address to Ping to Test my Internet Connection ?